# Angular service passing integer url params getting called twice appending Param value to API call

Tags: angular, observable, httpclient

I am calling a service in component and passing parameter from routetlink

What I have is below

Component

```
ngOninit(){
let id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));// value is 1
    this.getProducts(id);
}


 getProducts(id: number) {
    this.myService.getProducts(id)
      .subscribe(val => {
        this.value= val;
      }
  }
```

in service

```
url ="..getdetails?id="

getProducts(id: number): Observable<Products> {
    this.url = `${this.Url}${id}`
    return this.http.get<Products>(this.Url);
  }
```

Here I am using url ="..getdetails?id=" because I need to pass integer in url. Httpurlparams method can only send strung value.

Here the issue I am seeing two xhr requests on network

```
"..getdetails?id=1"
"..getdetails?id=11"
```

What I expect is only one network call 
I referred docs and saw cold observable will call twice. But in my case it is appending wrong id on second request. Please guide me how can  I do it...

Comment: Seems like `ngOninit()` gets called twice, and each time with different route params. Is some redirection happening? I'd try logging all router events to investigate further.

Comment: Exactly I saw it called twice but each time params is same. I'd each time same.

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint inside ngOninit?

Comment: I do also I put console as well

Comment: Try to put a console.log at this line `this.myService.getProducts(id)
      .subscribe(val => { 
       console.log(val);
        this.value= val;
      }`
How much it is called ?

Comment: Can you please add your component implementation logic and service provided at component or module level?

Comment: Spritzig first time expected object and second time null

Comment: Oke make something like this.
`this.myService.getProducts(id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(val => {  this.value= val; }`
and try if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `ngOninit()` is called twice is a different issue. The different query string param is caused by

```
this.url = `${this.Url}${id}`
```

What is happening here is that `this.url` gets mutated in first call to the service. In second call, this mutated value of `this.url` is used, and `1` is appended to it causing the issue.

Use block scope with `let` keyword.

Example of reproducing your issue and solution:

```
let url ="..getdetails?id="
let id = 1;

url = `${url}${id}`;
console.log(url);
url = `${url}${id}`;
console.log(url);

function setUrl(id) {
  console.log('Within a function...');

  let url = "..getdetails?id="

  url = `${url}${id}`;
  console.log(url);

}

setUrl(1);
setUrl(1);
```

See output:

```
$ node app.js
..getdetails?id=1
..getdetails?id=11
Within a function...
..getdetails?id=1
Within a function...
..getdetails?id=1
```

Solution:

```
 setUrl(url:string, id:number) { 
  url = `${url}${id}`;
  console.log(url);
  return url;
}

getProducts(url:string, id: number): Observable<Products> {

  return this.http.get<Products>(this.setUrl(url, id));
}
```